# Alexa will not play audio from a stream using lambda and python

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I can not for the life of me understand why this isnt working.

Here's my lambda function

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    url = "https://prod-65-19-131-166.wostreaming.net/kindred-wcmifmmp3-128"
    return build_audio_response(url)

def build_audio_response(url):
    return {
        "version": "1.01",
        "response": {
            "directives": [
                {
                "type": "AudioPlayer.Play",
                "playBehavior": "ENQUEUE",
                "audioItem": {
                    "stream": {
                        "token": "sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf3ew234235wtetgdsfgew3534tg",
                        "url": url,
                        "offsetInMilliseconds": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "shouldEndSession": True
    }
}
```

When I run the test in dev portal. I get a response as I should but its missing the directives.

```
{
  "version": "1.01",
  "response": {
  "shouldEndSession": true
},
  "sessionAttributes": {}
}
```

Alexa just says "There was a problem with the requested skills response."

Well I think its because the directives arent making it over. But I've tested the stream, it works. It's https. Theres a token. What am I missing?

Comment: I got a cert error when navigating to that URL... could that be related?

Comment: I fixed that problem but its still not working for some reason. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That response from Alexa means that the skill has returned an invalid response that Alexa doesn't know how to parse.

If you haven't already, you should check your CloudWatch logs for the Lambda function to see if any errors are arising there: https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#

To the best of my knowledge, the developer portal still doesn't display directives, so you don't want to test there. From the developer portal Alexa skill test page:

> Note: Service Simulator does not currently support testing audio
>   player directives and customer account linking.

What you can do to debug further if no errors found in CloudWatch is copy/paste the `Service Request` from that page and use it as a custom test for your Lambda function. On the Lambda page, click the `Actions` drop down and select `Configure Text Event` and paste your request from the developer portal into that. That'll give you a better picture of the response you're returning to Alexa. If you can't figure this out, add that response here and we'll try to puzzle things out a bit more.